# How to create a subset from a set of values within a column in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with 62 columns and 110 rows. In the column "date_observed" I have 57 dates with some of them having multiple records for the same date.

I am trying to extract only 12 dates out of this. They are not in any given order.

I tried this:

```
datesubset <- original %>% select (original$date_observed == c("13-Jun-21","21-Jun-21", "28-Jun-21", "13-Jul-21", "20-Jul-21", "8-Aug-21", "9-Aug-21", "25-Aug-21", "31-Aug-21", "8-Sep-21", "27-Sep-21"))
```

But, I got the following error:

> Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
> x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
> i It must be numeric or character.

I did try searching here and on google but I could find results only for how to subset a set of columns but not for specific values within columns. I am still new to R so please pardon me if this was a very simple question to ask.

Comment: You need to use `filter()` not `select()`. Also in dplyr you can skip the dollar sign and simply just call the variable.

Comment: Better if you make your question reproducible and include a sample of your data using `dput(original)`. As @Godrim points out one way to do this is using `filter(original, date_observed %in% c(vector_of_dates))` assuming the dates are formatted as strings.

Answer (score 2):

In `{dplyr}`, the `select()` function is for selecting particular columns, but if you want to subset particular rows you want to use `filter()`.

The logical operator `==` will also compare what is on the left, to *EVERYTHING* on the right, giving you a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` for each row, rather than just a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each row, which is what you are after.

What I think you are after is the logical operator `%in%` which checks to see if what is on the left appears at all on the right, and returns a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

As was mentioned, inside of *tidyverse* functions you don't need the `$`, you can just input the column name as in the example below.

I don't have your original data to double check, but the example below should work with your `original` data frame.

```r
specific_dates <- c(
  "13-Jun-21",
  "21-Jun-21",
  "28-Jun-21",
  "13-Jul-21",
  "20-Jul-21",
  "8-Aug-21",
  "9-Aug-21",
  "25-Aug-21",
  "31-Aug-21",
  "8-Sep-21",
  "27-Sep-21"
)

datesubset <- original %>%
  filter(date_observed %in% specific_dates)
```